# How to imput a value in a field to cread a calculation Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm creating a dashboard in tableau.

I have a table with a total payment.
And I'd like to know if it's possible to create a imput field to reduce that payment, like a hand imput discount.

i.e. if the total payment is 2000 USD and we want to give a 500 USD disct, create a imput field that recieve the value and discount it.

Also this discount value is somehow discused and not indexed in any database so I cant connect to tableau.

Answer (score 1):

you can try doing a calculated column

```
Discounted amount = [original_price_col_name] - 500
```

or `Discounted amount = [original_price_col_name] * .20`

so the new discounted price will appear in a new column called Discount amount

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you used a Parameter to perform this in a more dynamic and user-friendly way. I have also added a calculation to show how to utilize the parameter.

1. Create an Integer or Float Parameter
2. Create a Calculated field to use the parameter in Tableau viz

[image]